# How to make this question suitable for this site?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

@Richard deleted a question of mine: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83396/whats-the-stamina-of-wolverine-on-bed

And, I respect her decision.

I want to make the question suitable for this site. I already tried my best to write sexual things indirectly (like I used bed, I never used f**k word, etc), but looks like it still needs work.

Please, help.

Comment: I see no reasonable way to make this (truly dreadful) question suitable for a 13+ audience.

Answer (score 9):

**Per my comment above, I see no reasonable way to make this question suitable for a [13+ audience.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/whats-our-tolerance-for-adult-content/1586#1586)**

A couple of points;

1) Even if we somehow managed to fix the unsavoury (and squicky) wording in the original question, your thesis; that sexual intercourse results in *injury* to the participants, simply isn't true. The main premise of your question is flawed.

2) Based on your prior track-record of closed questions, I suspect you posed this question less out of genuine interest in knowing the answer and more to provoke a response by asking a **deliberately inappropriate** question you knew would get closed.

Comment: Your both points are wrong. 1. When you work out in gym, your tissues are injured (that's why you need protein to heal).. Sex is mother of workouts. 2. You can't accuse someone like that. That thing requires research in psychology (that's also not 100% perfect).