# Should we have tag and special treatment for mature questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The site has [slight tolerance for mature questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/whats-our-tolerance-for-adult-content), but [sometimes you don't have a way](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6691/how-to-make-this-question-suitable-for-this-site).

Should we have a special tag for such questions and clicking such questions should ask whether users are 18+ or not?

Comment: Nothing keeps kids away from bad things as well as a popup asking them if they're really over 18.

Comment: @phantom42 Still, that's how laws deal with it. Right? At least, parents can take care from there (there are softwares to monitor such 18+ warning pages).

Comment: "sometimes you don't have a way" Don't ask questions unsuitable for a 13+ audience on a site that has a 13+ audience. Ask them somewhere else. There's your way.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that in all of the discussions about "adult material" we've had, *nobody* has ever stepped forward to try to define it. The closest we've had was categorizing  bestiality as an adult-only topic.

Comment: @phantom42 I'm sortof ok with that; I would hate to have a list of pre-defined "definitely too racy" topics because context is everything. I assume anything that's explicitly *illegal* in the jurisdiction where StackExchange is hosted would be automatically off-topic, which would cover bestiality and child porn.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I am too. The whole concept of "mature" and "adult" subjects is too subjective, IMO. Also consider the fact that movies are now rated R for containing smoking and cursing.

Comment: Additional related discussion: [Should questions about sex and other adult activities be off-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3043/5184)

Comment: @phantom42 (To your first comment) "What do you call this?" CAPTCHA with an image of a cassette!  ;)

Comment: I totally misread the title of your question. I thought you were asking about a special tag for questions about written fiction as opposed to comic books, games, movies and TV shows.

Answer (score 13):

There are three major problems with your proposal:

First, and most importantly, you're making a broad assumption that such questions are *welcome* here by the community. As near as I can tell, that is not the case. The target audience (13+ users) is inclusive because that's what we want, not because we can't figure out how to target a different audience. As @alexwlchan says, there are other places where such questions would be perfectly at-home, just not here. (Try reddit?)

Second, we would be relying on the person asking the question, plus every subsequent high-rep user with edit privileges, to know whether their question was "bad enough" to warrant the tag; people under-tagging would negate the point, and people over-tagging would likely hide perfectly good questions where lots of people won't see them.

Finally, assuming there was consensus that your idea was a good one, we would be asking the developers of the Stack Exchange software to make a significant change to the way the site runs, specifically to allow a question that most of the community thinks is terrible. I don't see much likelihood of that proposal getting pushed through anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

So far as a new tag is concerned:  **No.**

Because:  Tags should be used **to attract answers**, not to deter readers.

As to whether any special treatment is necessary:  Use `>!` blocks if you want.