# Favorite Question and Answers from Fourth Quarter 2021

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

The post is now live. [Favorite Questions and Answers from Fourth Quarter 2021](https://thesffblog.com/2022/01/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-fourth-quarter-2021/)

### Origin

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from October 1st 2021 through December 31th 2021.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2021/10/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2021/10/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2021/10/01)

**I will be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter year. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/revision/1483709/1819138/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/revision/1483710/1819137/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Additionally if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

I liked this question. It was inspired by a [Q](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/27977/how-realistic-is-a-ceiling-crawl-cling-can-it-actually-be-done) on Climbing:SE and created some nice cross-site chatter.

- [How was this shot of River Tam on the ceiling managed in Serenity?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/257047/how-was-this-shot-of-river-tam-on-the-ceiling-managed-in-serenity)

---

I spent quite a lot of time researching this one and I really want to find an answer that goes beyond "*it's something weird that Villeneuve shoved in because he thought it was cool*". Hopefully the director will be a little more forthcoming in future.

- [What was the black spider creature in Villenueve's Dune, Part One?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255273/what-was-the-black-spider-creature-in-villenueves-dune-part-one)

---

And who doesn't love an answer that comes straight from the horse's mouth.

- [How to pronounce Fritz Leiber's name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255741/how-to-pronounce-fritz-leibers-name)

Comment: I’m noting a general hatred of irreverent questions about sex. My question whether Jacen Solo still plucks his own balls smooth; I figured it was decently composed question with exhaustive sourcing, and boy was the downvote reaction swift and violent, with comments like “why ask about _that_?” Lol. Like I’ve posted some stupid and pointless questions, just bad questions all around and they didn’t get downvoted to half the time or magnitude as Jacen’s plucked balls did.

Comment: @SillybutTrue There's a long history of meta discussion about such questions: [What's our tolerance for adult content?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1582/31394) (2012), [Should questions about sex and other adult activities be off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3043/31394) (2013), [May I ask a question about sex or explicit content in A Song of Ice and Fire books?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10251/31394) (2016), [Should we have a policy on questions about adult topics in SFF?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11728/31394) (2018), ...

Comment: @RandalThor Aaaah. That is informative. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Topic challenges

The fourth quarter of 2021 saw the continuation of SFF.SE's [topic challenge program](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13211/31394), with three topic challenges completed during this quarter: [Gene Wolfe](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13486/31394), [Samuel R. Delany](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13508/31394), and [Elizabeth Moon](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13553/31394).

- The October challenge produced five questions from two distinct users (Buzz, Rand al'Thor). Only two of them were answered (Wolfe's enigmatic work is known for giving rise to many questions and few answers), and I chose to reward friggle's answer to [Is the Sante Croix officer actually Number Five's brother?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/254573/31394) as it was based on an in-depth analysis of hints and clues in the text rather than just an easy search for a quote.
- The November challenge produced nine questions (plus one closed and deleted) from four distinct users (Silly but True, Clara Diaz Sanchez, David Siegel, Spencer) and eleven answers. My favourites, based largely on answer quality, were [In Samuel R. Delany’s Dhalgren, what catastrophe befell the city of Bellona?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/255579/31394) and [Do the events in Empire Star happen only once, the same way over and over, or slightly differently in different iterations?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/256650/31394) Again, these posts saw a lot of in-depth knowledge and analysis of the works in question, rather than simple find-a-quote answers.
- The December challenge produced two questions from two distinct users (Basya, just me). They were both good questions with good answers, but I decided to promote [In "The Deed of Paksenarrion", what race is the Kuakgan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/258258/31394) with a bounty for just me (a new user whose first participation in the site was for this topic challenge).

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be downvoted, but ... \*shrug\*. Jack doesn't care about downvotes when collating these answers for the blog post.

Comment: People who get downvoted here tend to get top billing on the blog, just to spite whomever thinks that downvoting anything said here is appropriate.